# The program does not print all the values from database

Tags: java, mysql, collections

**readAllItemsFromDb.java**

```
public List<Item> readAllItemsFromDb() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            con=(Connection)DatabaseConnectionManager.conn;

             Statement statement = null;
                try {
                    statement = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                String s = "SELECT * FROM cheese_tbl";

                try {
                    ResultSet srs = statement.executeQuery(s);
                    while(srs.next())
                    {
                        Cheese cheese = new Cheese();
                        cheese.setId(srs.getInt("id"));
                        cheese.setDescription(srs.getString("description"));
                        cheese.setWeight(srs.getFloat("weight"));
                        cheese.setPrice(srs.getFloat("price"));
                        cheese.setManufacturingDate(srs.getDate("mfg_date"));
                        cheese.setUseBeforeMonths(srs.getInt("UsebeforeInmonths"));

                        if(srs.getString("CheeseType").equals("Mozzarella"))
                            cheese.setCheeseType(CheeseType.Mozzarella);             
                        else if(srs.getString("CheeseType").equals("Easy_Spread"))
                            cheese.setCheeseType(CheeseType.Easy_Spread);
                        else if(srs.getString("CheeseType").equals("Cottage"))
                            cheese.setCheeseType(CheeseType.Cottage);            
                        else if(srs.getString("CheeseType").equals("Cheddar"))
                            cheese.setCheeseType(CheeseType.Cheddar);
                        Map<Ingred,Float> map = new HashMap<Ingred,Float>();
                        map.put(Ingred.protein,srs.getFloat("protein"));
                        map.put(Ingred.vitamin,srs.getFloat("vitaminB1"));
                        map.put(Ingred.fat,srs.getFloat("fat"));

                        cheese.setCalorieTable(map);

                        CheeseList.add(cheese);
                    }
                    System.out.println(CheeseList);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return null;
    }
```

The code works well till **it prints usebeforeinmonths**. But afterwards it prints null values.

output of my code is
success in connection
[1001 Mozzarella Cheese - Best for Pizza Preparation 200.0 200.0 2014-01-09 12 null, 1002 Goat Cheese Low calories -Easy Spread 300.0 300.0 2014-01-10 3 null, 1003 Cottage Cheese High Protine and Energy 400.0 400.0 2014-05-28 6 null]

It does not print type of cheese, protein, vitamin and  fat values.

Please help me with it.

Thank you.

**Cheese.java**

```
package com.bean;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Cheese extends Item {
    public CheeseType cheeseType ;
    public Map<Ingred,Float> calorieTable = new HashMap<Ingred,Float>();

    public Cheese() {
    }
    public CheeseType getCheeseType() {
        return cheeseType;
    }
    public void setCheeseType(CheeseType cheeseType) {
        this.cheeseType = cheeseType;
    }
    public Map<Ingred, Float> getCalorieTable() {
        return calorieTable;
    }
    public void setCalorieTable(Map<Ingred, Float> calorieTable) {
        this.calorieTable = calorieTable;
    }       
}
```

CheeseType class has

```
package com.bean;

    public enum CheeseType {
        Mozzarella ,Easy_Spread,Cottage,Cheddar
    }
```

**Ingred.java**

```
    package com.bean;

    public enum Ingred {
        protein,vitamin,fat
    }
```

Comment: Where is your cheese class?

Answer (score 0):

got the answer

public String toString()
    {
        return String.format(getId()+" "+getDescription()+" "+getWeight()+" "+getPrice()+" "+getManufacturingDate()+" "+getUseBeforeMonths()+" "+getExpiryDate()+" "+calorieTable+" "+cheeseType);
    }